# Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with the following property: $a \leq 1$ for $a$ in $A$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with the following property: $a \leq 1$ for $a$ in $A$

1. Give an example that sup$A = 1$
2. Give an example that sup$A < 1$

What does it mean to give examples of such conditions? Does it mean to pick different sets of $A$ that satisfy those conditions?

If so, how does a set have the supremum that $ \leq 1$? Don't all sets have one supremum if exists?

Comment: "Does it mean to pick different sets of A that satisfy those conditions?" : yes. 

"If so, how does a set have the supremum that ≤1?" : you have to find a set whose unique supremum is a number which is $\leq 1$.

Comment: @peter.petrov Do you know a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that has more than one supremum ?...

Comment: @peter.petrov The OP says "if exists", so it deals with the unicity of the supremum, not the existence. And of course, the supremum, *if it exists*, is unique. So the answer to OP's last question is yes.

Comment: In the way you asked the question I think the aim is to give an example of set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such all its elements are $\le 1$ and such that $\sup A = 1$ or such that $\sup A < 1$

Comment: @Gabrielek There's another question asking to prove sup$A \leq 1$, so I think your aim is correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If we take $A = (0, 1)$ this is an example for 1)

If we take $A = (0, 0.5)$ this is an example for 2)

And yes, every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has a unique supremum (if it exists).

Comment: I made my answer almost the same but I did not see that there was your. Do not delete answers immediately because it has no sense repeating the same things twice. (I think you deleted this answer for a while)

Comment: @Gabrielek I didn't delete it, no. I can pick other constants to avoid collisions, NP

Comment: No problem, maybe then it was a delay of the servers. Excuse me for the "aggression".

Answer (score 1):

In the way you asked the question I think the aim is to give an example of set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such all its elements are $\le 1$ and such that $\sup A = 1$ or such that $\sup A < 1$

To answer the first question take for example $A :=(0,1) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. It clearly has $\sup A = 1$

For the second just take $A:= (-1,0)$.